# are any Paris Metro stations outside zones 1-3?

Tags: trains, public-transport, paris

In Paris you have the RER lines, which are denoted by letters, and the Paris Metro, which are denoted by numbers.

My question is...  are there any Paris Metro stations that are outside of zones 1-3?

Marne-la-Vallée Chessy (the station you'd use for Disneyland Paris) is in zone 5 but the Paris Metro does not go there - just the RER. RER A, to be exact.

Versailles-Chantiers (the station you'd use for Versailles) is in zone 4 but, again, the Paris Metro does not go there - just RER C.

Mairie d'Issy, the southern terminus of line 12, is in zone 2.

Based on my spot checking, it does indeed seem to be the case that all Paris Metro stations are in zones 1-3 but my spot checking isn't comprehensive.

As for why this is relevant...  if every destination you're going to be visiting in Paris can be accessed through numbered routes then that means that a Paris Tour travel pass for zones 1-3 would be sufficient vs the more expensive zones 1-5 pass.

Comment: Does it actually work that way? Unlike RER stations, metro stations in zone 3 like Asnières - Gennevilliers - Les Courtilles or Créteil - Préfecture can actually be reached with a regular ticket T+, do travel passes work differently?

Comment: @Relaxed - in my experience, metro stations (unlike RER stations) don't require you "badge out", so to speak. But it could be more of an issue if you're doing a round trip.

Comment: Yes, that's true, there is no exit gates on the metro precisely because a regular T+ ticket is valid all the way into zone 3 and it doesn't matter what ticket allowed you to enter. By contrast, to use the RER or Transilien into zone 3, you need a pass or origine-destination ticket, the T+ ticket is only valid in zone 1. That's why I was wondering what makes you think the location of metro stations matters at all.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Based on [the RATP map of Paris transportation lines](https://www.ratp.fr/plan-de-ligne/img/rer/Plan-RER-et-transiliens.1646316579.png): No, there aren't any Metro stations outside of zones 1-3.

In fact, the Metro network is *almost* entirely within zones 1 and 2, there are just a few lines which extend into zone 3 for their final couple of stops.

> As for why this is relevant... if every destination you're going to be visiting in Paris can be accessed through numbered routes then that means that a Paris Tour travel pass for zones 1-3 would be sufficient vs the more expensive zones 1-5 pass.

I think you'd be better making this decision based on looking where your intended destinations are rather than abstracting to whether or not the Metro in general goes outside of zone 3. What if one of your destinations isn't on a Metro line? Last time I visited Paris there were multiple places I visited which were best reached by tram or bus. They were all within zones 1-3, but knowing there are no zone 4 metro stations wouldn't have told you that!

Comment: The link is broken ("origin DNS error")

Comment: @user253751 it seems to be working here, even from a new browser (i.e. not just cached). In my experience that error message normally indicates a temporary technical issue from a [CDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network).

Answer (score 5):

To add to the previous answer :

The Metro line 14 is [set to](https://www.ratp.fr/en/groupe-ratp/metrotrains/m14-extension-orly-airport) open its connection down to Orly Airport in 2024, which would be firmly in Zone 4

Comment: (+1) Not only line 14, there are a bunch of stations outside zone 3 planned on line 15, 16, 17, and 18. But I am curious to know if you have heard something about the fare structure for these future lines? If the current rule of being able to use a T+ ticket on the whole metro network remains, it would be a very cheap airport transfer indeed.

Comment: @Relaxed Those 15+ lines aren't part of the main Paris Metro *per se* (they are part of the Grand Paris Express) even though they'll be administered and advertised as Metro, which is why I didn't mention them

Comment: For the fare structure, nothing has been said, but I am imagining something akin to La Défense on line 1, where the station is in zone 3 for RER, Transillien, and Tram, but if you come on line 1 a single t+ is valid. I would see something akin to that be very appropriate. But again, this is pure speculation

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by Grand Paris Express not being part of the Paris metro but line 14 is definitely part of the former. Line 15, 16, 17 and 18 have much in common with it including the fact that it will go much further from the center than line 1 (or any of the other including 13…). That's why I am curious to know how the fare structure will look like. I would certainly like to be able to take them with a T+ ticket but €1.69 to go all the way to Orly would be very cheap.

Comment: @Relaxed The price for a Tram+metro ride from Orly is 2 t+ tickets (one for the tram and one for the metro so 3.8€ at unitairy price), the Line 14 will be at least 2x that to be logical I guess but it's too far ahead to know about that

Comment: @Relaxed Actually, it seems the [authority is not wanting to](https://www.20minutes.fr/paris/4033738-20230421-region-ile-france-dement-tarification-derogatoire-prolongement-ligne-14) make it more expensive that a normal ticket even through to Orly. But it's set at all, I have fears of it being way too popular, 1.69 to a airport is definitely appealing compared to 10 now